# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO

Tags: socket.io, swift4.1, xcode9.4

I've implemented swift4 custom framework with using of socketIO,
added **socket.io-client-swift** through carthage. 
in build phase added run script build phase

[image]

after generating of custom framework file , added into project embedded  Binaries.
 importing and creating a object for custom framework class. calling some methods in that class.
 while initialisation time getting below error.
***dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B1DF0219-7224-4DE1-A2F4-5722B40C907D/Testing.app/Frameworks/Connect.framework/Connect
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B1DF0219-7224-4DE1-A2F4-5722B40C907D/Testing.app/Frameworks/Connect.framework/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO: required code signature missing for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B1DF0219-7224-4DE1-A2F4-5722B40C907D/Testing.app/Frameworks/Connect.framework/Frameworks/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO'***

tired to do these steps

- cleared Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- changed signin auto-signing to manual

is there any way to resolve above issue
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?